# Variable initialize ways

Tags: c++, boost

I can initialize the boost::format variable in two ways:

First:

```
void foo()
{
  boost::format format{"Hellow %1% %2%"};
  format % "Dear" % "user";
  // do something with format
}
```

Second way:

```
void foo()
{
  boost::format v = boost::format {"Hellow %1% %2%"} % "Dear" % "user";
  // do something with format
}
```

I wonder, if either is more effective or not.

Thank you.

Comment: "The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes." - do you mean, I edited the question to mean something else. Regardless, it is still unclear.

Comment: @sehe How can I make this question clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding:

The overhead in that case is not where we think it is. Interesting question though.

Let's see what the first function does:

```
boost::format format{"Hellow %1% %2%"};
format % "Dear" % "user";
```

This creates an instance of format. The second line does not affect any result to any other new variable. It "simply" uses an operator overload that is dealt with internally, by the class boost::format. No new assignment is made.

Which is the main difference with the second way to do it. You assign, on top of the work already done, the result to a new variable. Which, for large numbers of execution, might cost (test it!).

As often, though, and depending on how much code those functions process, declaring your functions as inline could be the real benefit here.

[c++ inline functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/2LywvCM9/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

The conversion to `std::string` requested in the 3rd example has a possible cost in execution time and memory usage, and can mislead someone reading the code. It's just unnecessary.

Comment: I'm not sure what the protocol is here: OP has removed one of the examples so this answer's reference to the 3rd example doesn't make sense.

Comment: vote the question? If not, how can I improve the answer like it would be voted

Answer (score 0):

`format % "Dear" % "user";` is just an expression that is *also* of type `boost::format`. As such there is no real difference between the two approaches (except for the values
 of the variables).

Yes, similar things exist for other types. E.g. replace `format` with `int`:

```
int i = int(10);
i * 7 + 5;
```

Is equivalent to

```
int(10) * 7 + 5;
```

It's just the same expression. You can assign it too, because the result of `10*7+5` is still int:

```
int i = int(10) * 7 + 5;
```

Comment: I see, how can I change the answer it would be voted

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I haven't looked into the implementation details, but I'd be really surprised if the analogy would be closer with "partial application" or "currying" (which is actually useful and can be zero-overhead, making the analogy fit again). However, as a general point, Boost Format is clear not primarily optimized for performance, so yeah, YMMV.